# How to clone one instance while chaining methods?

Tags: php, oop

In my class, I have

== a private var called `$foo`

== public method called `set()` and `change()`

== another public method called`show()`

Here is some example code to help explain:

```
class xyz  {
    private $foo;
    public function set() {
        $this->foo = new Foo();
        return $this;
    }
    public function change($args) {
        $this->foo = new Foo($args);
        return $this;
    }
    public function show() {
        return $this->foo->print();
    }
}
```

This is using chaining method. So when I say:

```
$x = new xyz();
echo $x->set()->show();          //Outputs VALUE 1
echo $x->change($args)->show();  //Outputs VALUE 2 (changed value)
```

**But problem is here:**

```
$x1 = $x->set();
$x2 = $x->change($args);
echo $x1->show();            //Outputs VALUE 2 (changed value)
echo $x2->show();            //Outputs VALUE 2 (changed value)
```

That means, I am not able to hold `$this` object inside `$x1` to not
able to use method `show()` for `$x1` obj, instead it is using
internal `$this`.

Comment: There's only one instance of `xyz`. If you `set` and `change` it, everything that holds a reference to it will see that change. You'd need to `clone` your object at some point or instantiate a new one.

Comment: Of course `$x`, `$x1` and `$x2` hold the same reference since you return it from your chaining methods.

Comment: Thanks, using clone, solved this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) behaviour of `change` method. 
To achieve that, you would need to make a clone of your object on any change.

Like so:

```
public function change($args) {
    $copy = clone $this;
    $copy->foo = new Foo($args);
    return $copy;
}
```